# SQL Query to select employee from each department

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query a query to select the oldest employee in each department. I was able to join all of the tables, and get the columns I would like. I not just need to pick the oldest start date of each department. IF the start date is the same for two employees list them also.

I tried doing a subquery of say employee ID is IN `MIN(s.startDate)` from the employment history table. This grabs all of MIN

Here is my top select statement:

```
SELECT 
    e.FirstName, e.LastName, MIN(edh.StartDate), department.Name
FROM.....
```

This is using the `AdventureWorks` sample database:

https://moidulhassan.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/adventureworks2008_schema.gif

Comment: Help us help you and share your table(s) structure(s). Also, please tag your question with the [tag:rdbms] you're using

Comment: Assume it's SQLS because of AdventureWorks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on sql server, a relatively recent one:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY department.name ORDER BY edh.startdate) rown 
  FROM ...
) x
WHERE x.rown = 1
```

The row number analytic will created a incrmeennting column of numbers, 1 being the earliest start date and proceedings in order. The partition makes the row numbering start at 1 for each department. Then we just selects all the 1 numbered rows. If you want ties (two people both start on same earliest date) use RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER. if you want to exclude ties based on some criteria (alphabetic first name) include it in the order by so Alice always gets 1 instead of Bob

If your sql server is so ancient it doesn't support row_number, then upgrade it. You can also take that query that finds the min start date per department (the one you have) and make it a subquery, strip it down to just what it needs to return a dept id and a start date, and join it back to the main query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT departmentid, MIN(startdate) as mindate FROM ... ) x
INNER JOIN
...
ON ...departmentid = x.departmentid AND ...startdate = x.mindate
```

Comment: I've never seen that before

Comment: Side trivia for you: I believe Oracle introduced row_number in version 8i around 1998. It took MS a few years to catch up but it's been around a while there too. Incredibly useful - have a read up on "sql server windowing functions"

Answer (score 1):

You could `rank` the employees by descending age, and take the first one from each department:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, DepatmetnName
FROM   (SELECT p.FirstName AS FirstName, 
               p.LastName AS LastName,
               e.BirthDate AS BirthDate,
               d.Name AS DepartmentName,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DepartmentID ORDER BY e.BirthDate DESC) AS rk
        FROM   Person p
        JOIN   Employee e ON p.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID
        JOIN   EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh ON e.BusinessEntityID = edh.BusinessEntityID AND
                                                edh.EndDate IS NULL
        JOIN   Department d ON edh.DepartmentID = d.DerpartmentID) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```